# What happens when a method is called through IDispatch with the wrong number/types of arguments

Tags: c++, com

If I call a method of a COM object through IDispatch (late-binding) with the wrong number/types of arguments, will some error code be returned, or will the program crash or have other malfunctions? I just want to know if late-binding with IDispatch is type-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from the actual implementation of the `Invoke` method of `IDispatch`; it may check if the parameters passed in `pDispParams` are correct or blindly use them, ignore the COM errors that arise from manipulating them in a wrong way or report these errors to the caller, ...

Still, if the interface you are calling uses the default `DispInvoke` function to implement `IDispatch::Invoke` you should be safe, since it implements reasonable sanity checks on the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using the global DispInvoke.